# "! You can't use `\raise' in internal vertical mode" error

Tags: errors, tex-core

I used the command `\raise` to superimpose a title to a writing.

I got the error

```
! You can't use `\raise' in internal vertical mode
```

which puzzled me for a while.

For those interested, here is my code :

```
\def\withHatTitle#1#2{% #1: title #2: content
\setbox1=\hbox{#2}
\setbox0=\hbox{%\leaders\hrule height3pt depth-2pt\hskip 5pt
\kern\fboxsep#1\kern\fboxsep\leaders\hrule height3pt depth-2pt\hskip 5pt}
\ifdim\wd1<\wd0\wd1=\wd0\fi% if title longer than content, title gives the size
\setbox0=\hbox{\makebox[\wd1]{\box0\leaders\hrule height3pt depth-2pt\hfill}}% complete title with hrule
\wd1=0pt \box1 \raise 11pt \box0}% superpose title and content
```

Comment: Maybe, if you tell what's the aim of this, you could receive advice about how to do it better.

Comment: You might want to start your definition with `\ifvmode\leavevmode\fi` to enable `\withHatTitle` to start a paragraph.

Comment: I made this macro in order to be able to have one line with a title followed by a ruler to "group" underneath several items that include checkboxes. (I have a picture of the result but I cannot find out to download it here). I posted this because I had this error I was unable to cope with.

Comment: @Henri Menke I adopted the solution since it is the more economical : nothing is added when it is not necessary (i.e. when already in horizontal mode). Thanks !

Comment: Note the definition is missing `%` from ends of lines and so adds two word spaces before the text, see the output from `[\withHatTitle{The title}{This is the text to be titled}]` which makes `[ space space This...titled]`

Answer (score 1):

The explanation for this error is that \raise is forbidden in vertical mode, that is roughly when Tex piles up boxes in vertical.

Thus, the solution is simple : exit from the vertical mode. A simple solution consists in enclosing my macro \withHatTitle with a \hbox command, as follows:

```
\hbox{\withHatTitle{The title}{This is the text to be titled}}
```

Hope this helps !

P.S. the former is true also with \lower.

Comment: beware that such a command will not act like any other latex command, no latex box making command starts with a box in this way `\mbox`, `\fbox`, `\includegraphics`, `\raisebox` (which is the latex version of `\raise` of course) all start out with `\leavevmode`

Answer (score 1):

As your suggested code uses `\makebox` it is clear this is intended for LaTeX. LaTeX box commands always use horizontal mode to avoid this and other problems.
The direct analogue of `\raise` is `\raisebox` but here a `tabular` seems more natural.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\withHatTitle[2]{\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}%
#1 \hrulefill\\%
#2\end{tabular}}

a \withHatTitle{The title}{This is the text to be titled}

\bigskip

\withHatTitle{The title}{This is the text to be titled}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The initial idea was to have a box, with a black outline, that groups several items (checkboxes in fact), horizontally placed, and a title on the upper border to name that group. Later, I simplified the box with only the upper border outlined.
Therefore, the name of the group is astride the border.